# How to convert String having key=value pairs to Json

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

myString =  `{AcquirerName=abc, AcquiringBankCode=0.2, ApprovalCode=00};`

I want to convert it to the following string.

```
{"AcquirerName": "abc", "AcquiringBankCode": 0.2, "ApprovalCode": 0};
```

How can I do it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson to convert the key-value String to Object and convert it into JSON. For Eg,

**Add the following dependency:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Your Model:**

```
class MyModel {
    String AcquirerName;
    double AcquiringBankCode;
    int ApprovalCode;
//getter //setter //constructor
}
```

**Verify:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Impl
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String myString = "{AcquirerName=abc, AcquiringBankCode=0.2, ApprovalCode=00}";
        MyModel myModel = gson.fromJson(myString, MyModel.class);
        String json = gson.toJson(myModel, MyModel.class);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

O/P: `{"AcquirerName":"abc","AcquiringBankCode":0.2,"ApprovalCode":0}`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can JSONObject.. see below example

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
main.put("Command", "CreateNewUser");
JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
user.put("FirstName", "John");
user.put("LastName", "Reese");
main.put("User", user);
```

For Json Data:

```
{
    "User": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Reese"
    },
    "Command": "CreateNewUser"
}
```